# Scalable Server using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

So I would like to build a scalable server with Cocoa that can handle a lot of clients.

I guess this won't be possible on a single server as they have a limit on their network connections or would it be possible? I then thought of a database that is shared between multiple processes (on the same, or a different server) in (nearly) realtime, so when a change in process A is made, processes B,C,D sync so all processes have the same data.
Is this the correct way to do it? Could this be made with CoreData or are there better alternatives? I have actually never heard of Cocoa being used in server systems, so is it a bad idea to write a server in it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

my vote for not use CoreData on server side, because sqlite not feet my criteria to server side DB, not sure that is good for concurrency access and multiple connection.

Comment: Concurrency is quite hard with CoreData, or at least it seems so based on the SO-questions I've read. What would be a good alternative to CoreData?

Comment: I think is related to db backend you chose, you should write data access layer by self

Comment: can you recommend any db backend that's good for a lot of data sets? i've always worked with MySQL until now but i want to have the db integrated in the app, not as a standalone process.

Comment: Is hard to say, because I don't know your requests/goals from db. If you have good experience with mysql why not to use it? No one can recommend you something valuable without deep dive in your problems. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use one of the many, many (many) ready-to-use services out there that already built a proven infrastructure that works and scales. It's not a trivial task.

FWIW we're using [quickblox](http://quickblox.com/).

Comment: looks great! but it seems more like a software for the end-user instead for keeping multiple server instances synced.

Comment: It's a framework/API you can use to built scalable apps, i.e. they've implented all the server services for you. It's pretty cool and has a free entry level.

Comment: I've read a little bit more and it really seems like a cool tool, I'll definitely put it on my list for future projects! But in this case of I need the data securely stored on my server(s). Although I guess this may be possible with the Small/Medium/Large plans it's focused mainly on different things than I need, which is a own manageable database.